# awk produces false positive on string match if that string was inserted by a sed command

Tags: arrays, bash, awk, sed

I have an input file, a reference file, and a script. The script reads parameters in the reference file; then it scans the input file for the same parameters and replaces their values *if the values are different*.

Whenever the script replaces values in the input file, it records the previous value with a timestamp, then writes the new value below it in a newline. This gives me a history of meaningful updates to parameters.

**Input File (test.txt)**

```
testx=1
# testy=2
#testz=3

foobar=2
path=/data/me/testing

plainpath=/data/me/stack

testw=4
```

**Reference File (ref.txt)**

```
foobar=10
path=$MY_HOME
plainpath=/data/you/stack
testy=stack
```

**script (script.sh) - Thanks to Ed Morton for the formatting**

```
#!/bin/bash

Timestamp=$(date '+%Y%m%d_%H:%M:%S')
myhome=/data/stack/testing

awk -F= -v stamp="$Timestamp" '
(NR == FNR && /=/ && !/^#/) {
    for (j = 2; j < NF; j++) {
        a[$1] = a[$1] $j "="
    }
    a[$1] = a[$1] $NF
}

(NR != FNR && $1 in a && $1 > 0) {
    if ($2 !~ a[$1]) {
        $0 = "###EDITED_ON " stamp " from " $2 " to\n" $1 "=" a[$1]
    }
}

(NR != FNR && /^#[ a-zA-Z]/) {
    b = $1
    sub(/# */, "", b)
    if (b in a) {
        $0 = b "=" a[b]
    }
}
(NR != FNR) {
    print
}

prep.txt test.txt > tmp && mv tmp test.txt

sed -i 's,$MY_HOME,'"$myhome"',g' test.txt
```

---

**Brief explanation of script (potentially skippable)**

For NR==FNR, awk stores the variables in ref.txt in a hash '*a*' with the variable name as key and the variable value as the paired value.

For NR != FNR, awk is scanning test.txt. It compares $1, a variable name, to check whether it's a key in the hash. If it's in the hash, it replaces the line with two lines. The first line has a timestamp and the old value. The second line has the parameter with the new value.

There is one additional NR != FNR block to account for parameters which are commented out. I have not written them to write a timestamp history here for simplicity of presentation.

---

**Target code line**

```
if($2 !~ a[$1])
```

This if conditions means that the code will not write if the replacement value is already the same as the value in the input file. This should ensure I only see meaningful updates from the script. Unfortunately, this is the line that is returning a false positive for matching strings inserted by sed.

**Problem**

There is a sed line below the awk code which substitutes variables. This allows me to conveniently write ref.txt with variables for frequently occuring values, and then substitute them all in one step at the end.

For some reason, when I substitute with sed, something about sed changes the nature of the inserted string. Even if the replacement value is the same, if I run the script a second time, awk will replace it and enter a timestamp for the new edit. It's making redundant updates.
Here is the output after running the script twice:

```
testx=1
testy=stack
#testz=3

###EDITED_ON 20200702_11:35:42 from 2 to
foobar=10
###EDITED_ON 20200702_11:35:42 from /data/me/testing to
###EDITED_ON 20200702_11:35:46 from /data/stack/testing to
path=/data/stack/testing

###EDITED_ON 20200702_11:35:42 from /data/me/stack to
plainpath=/data/you/stack

testw=4
```

Notice that "plainpath" and "foobar" are not edited any further. Path, however, which was defined in ref.txt by the variable $MY_HOME and substituted out by sed, is continually updated with the same value. I can run this infinitely, and it will always update this line.

Eliminating the sed line isn't a crisis for my project, but I am interested in why sed and awk interact this way.

**Questions**

- Does anyone know why sed changes how the awk script interprets a text
  string?
- Is there a workaround for me to expand variables in the file while
  retaining expected awk functionality, or other improvements in
  general?

Thank you very much!

Comment: didn't read the question. check with hexdump what is the difference

Comment: `This gives me a history of meaningful` Use `git`. Or other _version-control system_ that exists... just to keep track of history of meaningful updates (well, called _versions_).

Comment: if sed changes something then you should compare file before and after sed to see whats the difference. please note it's nature of sed to create a new file (new inodes) the -i flag is not really what it claims. to avoid this you can use redirect sed ... test.txt > tmp && cat tmp > test.txt

Comment: Actually, I just realized why. It's rather dumb, but a[$1] = $MY_HOME, so of course when they are compared, they won't be the same. The sed expands it into text after awk places it, so on the next comparison $2 becomes the text while a[$]1 still returns $MY_HOME. I tested it now and confirmed. I guess the only false positive was my idea I had run into a spurious interaction. I should have realized it sooner. Should I delete the question?

Answer (score 0):

If your script considers both path values as different...

```
###EDITED_ON 20200702_11:35:46 from /data/stack/testing to
path=/data/stack/testing
```

... then you ought to assume that what is after the equal sign (the field separator in your awk script) is indeed different, but the actual problem is that you don't see the difference.

If you can't see it, it is probably because the difference is made of space characters at the end of the line, for example " ", tabulation or even carriage return (CR) if your file was edited on Windows (lines end with CR+LF on Windows but Unix only considers the LF char).

Use an hex editor or `cat -A` to see what is hidden to your eyes.